# Get user list from table-1, then compare with data from table-2

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I get user list from data-1 table as seen in code below.

```
    DatabaseReference rootReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference reference = rootReference.child("data-1")
    ValueEventListener listener= new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            final ArrayList<String> userList= new ArrayList<>();
            for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String foundUserId= dSnapshot.getKey();
                if (condition) {
                    userList.add(foundUserId);   
                    //step one completed: userList is full with all necessary users
                    //Now how to iterate it and compare it with data from table-2?
                }

            }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    };

    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);

}
```

So far so good, `userList` has all the users found from `data-1` table. But, I still need to filter out some users and add them to second list called `filteredUserList`. I need to filter them out by comparing each user to the current user that's saved on the `final` variable `currentUserId`

I get list of users from `data-1`, where each user has a list of users under it like so:

```
data-1
  |_____uid1
  |      |_____uid3: true
  |      |_____uid4: true
  |
  |_____uid25
         |_____uid34: true
         |_____uid101: true
```

You see in `data-1` each user has a list of users under it, which is how I first get to fill `userList`.

`table-2` has timestamp node, and this is its structure:

```
table-2
   |
   |____userid1
   |         |
   |         |_____timestamp: timestamp
   |
   |____userid2
             |
             |_____timestamp: timestamp

      //and so on..
```

What I want to do is, after I have `userList` filled with users, I need to check whether each user's `timestamp` is within a certain time delta from the current user. So I need to iterate the `userList`, and compare each user's `timestamp` with the current user's `timestamp`. But I can't get it to work because in order to get each user's timestamp I need a new `onDataChange`, and in a for loop, but it's out of scope, and it's also async so it's never working! What would be the correct way to make it work? I've been trying for over a week now. Is it even possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of is to get current user `timestamp` and then query the entire `users` node and compare current user `timestamp` with the other user timestamps.

> I need to filter them out by comparing each user to the current user

So to solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users")
DatabaseReference uidRef = usersRef.child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long currentUserTimestamp = dataSnapshot.child("timestamp").getValue(Long.class);
        String currentUserKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();

        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    long timestamp = dataSnapshot.child("timestamp").getValue(Long.class);
                    if(currentUserKey != ds.getKey()) {
                        if(currentUserTimestamp > timestamp) {
                            //Do something
                        } else {
                            //Do something else
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
            }
        };
        usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

**Edit:** Accoding to the comments and edited question, please see the code below:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference table2Ref = rootRef.child("table-2");
DatabaseReference uidRef = table2Ref.child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long currentUserTimestamp = dataSnapshot.child("timestamp").getValue(Long.class);
        String currentUserKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();

        DatabaseReference currentUserKeyRef = rootRef.child("data1").child(currentUserKey);
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String userKey = ds.getKey();

                    DatabaseReference userKeyRef = table2Ref.child(userKey);
                    ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for(DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                long timestamp = d.child("timestamp").getValue(Long.class);
                                if(currentUserTimestamp > timestamp) {
                                    //Do something
                                } else {
                                    //Do something else
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
                        }
                    };
                    userKeyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
            }
        };
        currentUserKeyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: But there are 2 tables, first is `data-1`, from which I get an array list of users first, then only from these specific users I need to filter it out, not from all users, because `data-1` has specific property where I first filter certain users, only then, I filter out by the timestamp found on the `users` table. You see in my code that I first filter out first from `data-1`. If you want, I will add more information with `data-1` structure

Comment: I added the structure of `data-1`, where I first get list of all necessary users that are found under our current user's id. If something is not understandable, please let me know so I'll fix it

Comment: So to understand better. For example, you want to access the data from `data-1 -> uid1` and get `uid3` and `uid4`, right? Using this two ids you want to get the data from `table-2`, right? Having the data for this two users, you want to compare theirs timestamp with the current user timestamp, is this correct?

Comment: A little too broad but just updated my answer. Tell me if it works now.

Comment: Still working on it, I will do it as soon as I see if it works!

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.